# iOS: APN auth Key for free developer account

Tags: ios, firebase

Do we need to enroll in the Apple Developer Program ($99) to get the APN auth key and certificate? I needed it to learn FireBase Cloud Messaging which asks for the APN certificate/auth-key to be uploaded. This is how my developer account looks like.

[image: Developer Account FREE iOS - require certificates profiles option]

Also, is there any other way I can generate a token for sending messages to FCM

Comment: Are you trying to implement push notification???

Comment: Yes, but through firebase , i want to perform a particular function after a notification is received through the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure Firebase for Push Notifications you need APNs certificate.

To unlock push notifications capability you need to enroll into the Apple Developer program (after that you will get access to Certificates, IDs & Profiles section of your developer account).

PS: [AppCoda: Implementing Push Notifications on iOS with Firebase](https://www.appcoda.com/firebase-push-notifications/)